# R - de-duplicate a list while maintaining order of records

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data about a series of events and would like to examine the changes so I don't really care about repeats of the same events.

This is what I have:

```
ID  Date        Item
1   1-Jan-19    A
1   5-Jan-19    A
1   8-Jan-19    B
1   15-Jan-19   A
2   1-Jan-19    A
2   5-Jan-19    A
2   8-Jan-19    B
2   15-Jan-19   B
3   1-Jan-19    B
3   5-Jan-19    A
3   8-Jan-19    B
3   15-Jan-19   A
4   1-Jan-19    A
4   5-Jan-19    A
4   8-Jan-19    A
4   15-Jan-19   B
```

From this, what I would like is:

```
ID Sequence
1   ABA
2   AB
3   BABA
4   AB
```

Using tidyverse I was able to get all into one list/variable but I can't figure out how to de-duplicate lists either in that step or a single step. To get it into a single variable I used mutate, group_by and paste0, code is below.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#create fake data
have = cbind(
    c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    c(43466, 43470, 43473, 43480, 43466, 43470, 43473, 43480, 43466, 43470, 43473, 43480, 43466, 43470, 43473, 43480),
    c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B")
)
#add names
names(have) = c("ID", "Date", "Value")
#convert to tibble
have = as_tibble(have)

#current non-working solution
want <- have %>%
        group_by(V1) %>%
        mutate(Order = paste0(V3, collapse = "|"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we can first `filter` out the `duplicates` based on `rleid` on the third column after grouping by first column and then do the `paste/str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
have %>% 
    group_by(V1) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(rleid(V3))) %>% 
    summarise(Sequence = str_c(V3, collapse=""))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  V1    Sequence
#  <chr> <chr>   
#1 1     ABA     
#2 2     AB      
#3 3     BABA    
#4 4     AB
```

---

Replace the 'V1', 'V3' with 'ID', 'Item' for the data showed first

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(rleid(Item))) %>%
   summarise(Sequence = str_c(Item, collapse=""))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

We can check for previous value with `lag` and use `filter` to remove the duplicates and paste the unique values together per group.

```
library(dplyr)

have %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  filter(V3 != lag(V3, default = FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(V3 = paste0(V3, collapse = ""))

#  V1    V3   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1     ABA  
#2 2     AB   
#3 3     BABA 
#4 4     AB
```

Comment: I was thinking about the `lag` one.